# Getting Error while making a purchase using Woocommerce stripe payment gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am trying to setup my Woocommerce site and I am getting an error while doing test purchase using `woocommerce-stripe` gateway plugin. I really need help here.

This is the error I am getting from stripe while doing a test purchase

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "You must specify a value for cross_border_classification.",
    "param": "cross_border_classification",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add more details about how you call this plugin?

Comment: Its called WooCommerce Stripe Payment Gateway
By WooCommerce

Comment: If you can help me here it will means alot to me. Thank you